# display confirm message to user if true value in data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i need to display confirm message using vuejs that if contains true field in data field that data coming from an api.i have given api outpt below and also if condition that is used to display alert message.
in below output there is no true. whenever true data comes then only alert should be displayed.

//API Data

```
{
    "BNG-JAY-137-003": false,
    "BNG-JAY-137-004": false, 
    "BNG-JAY-137-005": false 
}
```

//below is my if condition and i am storing API output to an vaiable 'selected_data'

```
if(this.selected_data){
    if(confirm("Do you want to Turn On All lights")){
        alert("Lights on")
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted checks if data is available then goes in the condition. If you want to check if out of all the data any is true. You need to loop on all the data and check if any is true and then display the alert or whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through your object to determine if any of the property contains `true` as a value. You can achieve this by doing something like this:

```js
let data = {
  "BNG-JAY-137-003": false,
  "BNG-JAY-137-004": true,
  "BNG-JAY-137-005": false
};

let hasTrue = false;

for(let key in data) {
  if(data[key]) {
    hasTrue = true;
    break;
  }
}

if(hasTrue) {
   if(confirm("Do you want to Turn On All lights")){
     alert("Lights on");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
if (Object.keys(selected_data).map(function(item) { 
    return selected_data[item]}).indexOf(true) >=0) {
       if(confirm("Do you want to Turn On All lights")) {
           alert("Lights on")
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm). It should always return a boolean which you can then apply to your logic. COmbine it with [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
function checkAndConfirm(object) {
    result = true;
    for (let key in Object.values(object))
        result = Object.values(object)[key] && result;

    if (result) {
        let confirmed = confirm("Do you want to turn on all lights?");
        if (confirmed) alert("Lights on")
    }
}

checkAndConfirm({ //should evaluate as false
    "BNG-JAY-137-003": false,
    "BNG-JAY-137-004": true, 
    "BNG-JAY-137-005": true
});
checkAndConfirm({ //should evaluate as true
    "BNG-JAY-137-003": true,
    "BNG-JAY-137-004": true, 
    "BNG-JAY-137-005": true
});
```

Comment: doesn't makes difference if you use confirm in if condition.